# How to select only last element without adding modifier class

Tags: html, css

I want to select only the last element with class "feature" without adding extra classes, only with pseudo selectors like :last-child but since the elements with class "feature" are not siblings it's not working at all. Can someone help me to solve this little problem.
Here is the HTML:

```
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <article class="feature">
                    <i class="fas fa-search-location fa-3x mb-3"></i>
                    <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Great location</h3>
                    <p class="feature__text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
                        unde?
                    </p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <article class="feature">
                    <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-3x mb-3"></i>
                    <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Free meals</h3>
                    <p class="feature__text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
                        unde?
                    </p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                <article class="feature">
                    <i class="fas fa-dumbbell fa-3x mb-3"></i>
                    <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Fitness room</h3>
                    <p class="feature__text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
                        unde?
                    </p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given markup you could use this selector

```
.row > div:last-child .feature {
  ...
}
```

this will match the `.feature` element inside the last `div` which is a direct child of `.row`.

Answer (score 1):

`:last-child` only works when the element in question is the last child of the container, not the last of a specific type of element. For that, you want :`last-of-type`

```
.col-lg-4:last-of-type article.feature {
  background-color:red
}
```

Comment: every .feature is the last-of-type for it's parent div so it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

try to make it like this way.

```css
.col-lg-4:last-child article.feature {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <article class="feature">
     <i class="fas fa-search-location fa-3x mb-3"></i>
     <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Great location</h3>
     <p class="feature__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
      unde?
     </p>
    </article>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <article class="feature">
     <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-3x mb-3"></i>
     <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Free meals</h3>
     <p class="feature__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
      unde?
     </p>
    </article>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
    <article class="feature">
     <i class="fas fa-dumbbell fa-3x mb-3"></i>
     <h3 class="heading-tertiary mb-5">Fitness room</h3>
     <p class="feature__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam illo nam quis sit
      unde?
     </p>
    </article>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will works for you.

Thank you...